# How to implement something similar to public_send for non-class variables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run a query in my Rails code:

```rb
  check1 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ...")
  check2 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT ...")
```

The tables used above will have columns for each business day of a month. So I have columns day1 till day23 and if a month has only 22 working days, then day23 will be null

Now I need to execute this for all 23 days

```rb
  if check1.day1 = check2.day1
    day1_style = <some value>
  end
```

I need to write the above 3 lines of code for all 23 days.

I can think of this:

```rb
  if check1.public_send(day#{n}) = check2.public_send(day#{n})
    day<how to represent n here?>_style = <some value>
  end
```

I know `public_send` will work for the if condition shown above.

How do I do the same for the next line to assign values for `day1_style`, `day2_style`, `day3_style` etc inside the loop shown above?

Comment: "I know public_send will work for the if condition shown above." - not quite, missing a bit of syntax there. And probably an = vs == error too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array.

```
day_styles = []
if check1.public_send("day#{n}") == check2.public_send("day#{n}")
  day_styles[n] = <some value>
end
```